# Spectral leakage of windowed vs un-windowed FFTs in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

The scipy fourier transforms [page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html#id1) states that "Windowing the signal with a dedicated window function helps mitigate spectral leakage" and demonstrates this using the following example

```
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
# Number of sample points
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = fft(y)
from scipy.signal import blackman
w = blackman(N)
ywf = fft(y*w)
xf = fftfreq(N, T)[:N//2]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.semilogy(xf[1:N//2], 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[1:N//2]), '-b')
plt.semilogy(xf[1:N//2], 2.0/N * np.abs(ywf[1:N//2]), '-r')
plt.legend(['FFT', 'FFT w. window'])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

However using `N=1599` (or values less that 1599) and `N=1600` (or values greater than 1600) gives very different results. When using N greater than 1600 the spectral leakage seems to be better in the un-windowed fft than the windowed one. This transition seem to occur at `N=1600` independent of the sampling. Why is this happening?

[image: N=1599]
[image: N=1600]

Comment: When your sample window contains an exact number of periods then this is a special case where there is no spectral leakage. In the general case, for real world signals, this does not occur, and windowing is normally required.

Comment: @PaulR can you please provide a reference or where this is documented, Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions here on StackOverflow already - search under the `[dsp]` tag for terms such as "spectral leakage" and you should find plenty of info.